# How to create a Firebase function triggered by a Firebase real time database record expiry date?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have a Firebase real-time database with specific records having expiration date fields (exp_date). How can I have a Firebase function that will execute for each of those records upon expiration of date in (exp_date) date field.

Comment: I would recommend rethinking the model. Imagine rather than having to perform actions upon expiry, check for expiry whenever you perform an action and if true, do what you want then and there. This way, you won't have to be regularly querying your db which can be costly over time.

Comment: Thank you. I'll rethink my strategy

Answer (score 0):

Such a trigger does not exist currently. You would need to implement something like [functions-cron](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron) to regularly query your database for records whose expiration has passed and delete them.